# PHP Class Database Connection Scope Issue

Tags: php, mysql, class, scope, code-reuse

For a new project that I'm doing in PHP I've created an SQLMethods class to connect to the database and perform queries. Tonight was the first night that I actually got to test it (I wrote it a week or so ago and forgot about it) and an unexpected error occured: When it was calling my ExecuteQuery() function, it wouldn't use the database I selected in the constructor.

The constructor:

```
    public function SQLMethods() {
        $SQLConnection = mysql_connect($SQLDBAddress, $SQLUserName, $SQLPassword);

        if (!$SQLConnection) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($SQLDB, $SQLConnection);
    }
```

The function in question:

```
    public function ExecuteQuery($Query) {
        mysql_query($Query, $SQLConnection) or die('Could not perform query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

Does anyone see what the issue might be? Does the connection close after the constructor completes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should declare $SQLConnection in your class, and you should refer to it as

```
 $this->SQLConnection
```

and not simply $SQLConnection.

Answer (score 2):

`$SQLConnection` doesn't exist within the `ExecuteQuery` method.

You can either pass it directly as a parameter to `ExecuteQuery`, or add an `sqlConnection` class property that is set in the constructor and accessed as `$this->sqlConnection` inside your class methods.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$SQLConnection` `ExecuteQuery()` is trying to use is created within another scope. (The `SQLMethods` function).

The connection closes when the PHP script has done its work or if you close it yourself (if the connection is made within that script)

You should skip the `$SQLConnection` variable within `ExecuteQuery` as stated by the php.net documentation

> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed.